# What is the structure of the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> What did they do about the problem?

I think the structure of the sentence is like the following:

- Subject = they
- Verb = do
- Object = What
- Adverbial = about the problem

Is it correct? Please explain it to me.

Comment: It is a question about a past action, hence the full verb is "did do", with inversion of the normal subject-verb-object order.

Comment: Yes, essentially. The dummy auxiliary "did" is also a verb.

Answer (score 0):

> What did they do about the problem?

What= Relative pronoun serving as an object (they did do [what])

Did= Auxiliary Do

They= Subject

Do= Verb

About = Preposition

Problem= Object of preposition

or

About the problem= Adverbial phrase modifying verb "do"

We can see that as TRomano said, there is inversion.

Comment: I'd say that interrogative "what" is object of "do", not a relative pronoun. They did _what_ about the problem?